# Clustering and Feature Selection For Audio Data

Tags: feature-selection, signal-processing

I'm very new to stats and I'm at a loss as to where to start with this problem. I'm not sure what tools or methods to use to extract meaningful answers from my data.

I'll try and describe the problem generally

Basically, I've extracted about 22 features or so from individual audio tracks of varying instrumentation(drums, guitars etc) on a frame by frame basis of each track, so they're effectively a time series of features in MATLAB. I've selected these features due to various literature I've read.

I know through listening that some of these tracks are similar, so they must therefore have common features. I want go through all my audio and identify which tracks have similar features to each other and identify what features makes them so similar. For example I want to know what are the common features to all the drum tracks I have. I effectively want to identify which are the best features to group the instruments by.

What kind of stat analysis do I need to do try and figure this out? Linear regression, time series analysis, Dynamic Time Warping?? I have no idea where to start. My knowledge of statistical methods is poor.

Comment: I changed the title and tags to be a bit more informative. If I misunderstood something, please let me know and I will change back.

Comment: No that's fine. :)